Relation between two norms
Let $p\ge 2$ and $w:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}_+$ be a weight function normalized such that $\|w\|_{L^1}=1$ (the examples I have in mind would be a Gaussian or a two-sided exponential for example).
With this, let
$$
\|F\|_{p,w}^p:= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |F(x)|²\cdot w(x-y)\,\mbox{d}x \right)^{\frac{p}2}\,\mbox{d}y.
$$
Are such type of norms studied anywhere?
In other words, if we measure the local $L^2$-norm at $y$ by
$$u(y)= \|F\|_{L^2(w(\cdot-y))}$$
we have that
$\|F\|_{p,\chi}=\|u\|_{L^p}$.
I would expect that for reasonable functions $\|F\|_{p,w}$ should behave somewhat like $\|F\|_{L^p}$.
In one direction I managed to relate those two norms. By Jensen's inequality we get
$$
\|F\|_{p,w}^p = \int \left(\int |F(x)|^2 \chi(x-y) \mbox{d}x\right)^{\frac{p}2} \mbox{d}y \le C \iint |F(x)|^p w(x-y) \,\mbox{d}x \,\mbox{d}y = C' \|F\|_{L^p}
$$
What about the other direction though? Does there exists a finite constant $C>0$ such that
$$
\|F\|_{L^p} \le C \|F\|_{p,w}, \, F\in L^p?
$$
If not, also a weaker statement could be potentially useful: For which subspaces $X\subseteq L^p$ does it hold that
$$
\|F\|_{L^p} \le C \|F\|_{p,w},\, F\in X
$$
for some finite $C>0$.
